# RHS Operator Overloading

Tags: c++

Say i have a custom datatype:

```
MyBYTE
```

and I want to overload the == operator so that it can be compared to a BYTE like so:

```
if(b == mb)
{
    //can't overload that operator
}
```

or

```
if(mb == b)
{
    //CAN overload that operator
}
```

as far as I'm aware when mb is on the right, I cannot overload an operator within the MYBYTE class. Is this true? If so are there any workarounds?

Comment: Just make the overload a free function and you can perfectly well overload it both ways.

Comment: You can find the answer [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3764604/5909613)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operators can be declared as free functions. Almost all binary operators (except `+=` and similar and `->*` and similar) can be overloaded this way.

```
bool operator==(const MyBYTE& lhs, const BYTE& rhs) {
    // do stuff here
}

bool operator==(const BYTE& lhs, const MyBYTE& rhs) {
    // do stuff here
}
```