# Template deduction complaints ambiguous candidates

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, ambiguous

I intend to implement the **multiplication operator** of my "Sparse Vector" and "Vector" classes. The following simplified code demo shows my problem

The *Vector* class in **Vector.hpp**

```
#pragma once

template <typename T>
class Vector 
{
public:
    Vector() {}

    template <typename Scalar>
    friend Vector operator*(const Scalar &a, const Vector &rhs)     // #1
    {
        return Vector();
    }
};
```

The *Sparse Vector* class in **SpVec.hpp**

```
#pragma once
#include "Vector.hpp"

template <typename T>
class SpVec 
{
public:
    SpVec() {}

    template <typename U>
    inline friend double operator*(const SpVec &spv, const Vector<U> &v)   // #2
    {
        return 0.0;
    }
};
```

The test code in **main.cpp**:

```
#include "Vector.hpp"
#include "SpVec.hpp"


#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    Vector<double> v;

    SpVec<double> spv;

    std::cout << spv * v;
    return 0;
}
```

I build the test program with

```
g++ main.cpp -o test
```

which gives the ambiguous template deduction error

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:13:26: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator*’ (operand types are ‘SpVec<double>’ and ‘Vector<double>’)
        std::cout << spv * v;
                    ~~~~^~~
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
SpVec.hpp:12:26: note: candidate: double operator*(const SpVec<T>&, const Vector<U>&) [with U = double; T = double]
    inline friend double operator*(const SpVec &spv, const Vector<U> &v)   // #2
                        ^~~~~~~~
In file included from main.cpp:1:0:
Vector.hpp:10:19: note: candidate: Vector<T> operator*(const Scalar&, const Vector<T>&) [with Scalar = SpVec<double>; T = double]
    friend Vector operator*(const Scalar &a, const Vector &rhs)     // #1
```

I expect the `#2` method definition is more close to my calling.

Please help me understand how the ambiguous error comes out and how to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I come up with another idea that the prior type information `Scalar` can be used with the [**SFAINE** feature](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) enabled by the `c++11` standard library struct [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if).

The codes:

**Vector.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class Vector
{
public:
    Vector() {}

    template <typename Scalar>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<Scalar>::value, Vector<T>>::type
    operator*(const Scalar &rhs) const// #1
    {
        std::cout << "Vector * Scalar called." << std::endl;
        return Vector();
    }

    template <typename Scalar>
    inline friend typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<Scalar>::value, Vector<T>>::type
    operator*(const Scalar &lhs, const Vector &rhs)
    {
        std::cout << "Scalar * Vector called." << std::endl;
        return Vector();
    }
};
```

**SpVec.hpp**

```
#pragma once
#include "Vector.hpp"

#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class SpVec
{
public:
    SpVec() {}

    template <typename U>
    inline double operator*(const Vector<U> &rhs) const // #2 as member function
    {
        std::cout << "SpVec * Vector called" << std::endl;
        return 0.0;
    }

    template <typename U>
    inline friend double operator*(const Vector<U> &lhs, const SpVec &rhs)
    {
        std::cout << "Vector * SpVec called" << std::endl;
        return 0.0;
    }
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "SpVec.hpp"
#include "Vector.hpp"

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Vector<double> v;
    SpVec<double> spv;

    double a = spv * v;
    a = v * spv;

    Vector<double> vt;
    vt = v * 2.0;
    vt = 2.0 * v;

    return 0;
}
```

Build the program with `c++11`

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o test
```

The result:

```
SpVec * Vector called.
Vector * SpVec called.
Vector * Scalar called.
Scalar * Vector called.
```

Comment: That's also a nice one !

Answer (score 0):

The argument to `operator*` are `SpVec<double>` and `Vector<double>`. It could be resolved to

`operator*(const Scalar &a, const Vector &rhs)` with `scalar` as `SpVec<double>` and `rhs` as `Vector<double>`.

It could also resolve to

`operator*(const SpVec &spv, const Vector<U> &v)` with spv as `SpVec<double>` and `U` as `double`.

One way of resolving this is to turn `Vector::operator*` to non-friend function.

```
Vector operator*(const Scalar &a)     // #1
{
    //The other argument here will be accessed using this pointer.
    return Vector();
}
```

and you can call it as

```
int main() 
{
   Vector<double> v;
   SpVec<double> spv;
   std::cout << spv * v; // will call #2
   v * spv;              //will call #1
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it!

Comment: Thanks.  This suggestion does work. For the deeper discussion, is it possible to make the two cases both work as no operands precedence need to be cared about for the user?

Comment: Nice answer.  However, this works only because you play with the order of the parameters (with an operator that is assumed to be commutative).

Comment: @Rubin I think the term you are looking for is commutate and not precedence. The commutative property says that `a*b` is equal to `b*a`. Precedence is used to decide in which order several operators are executed: `a + b * c` where multiplication has a higher precedence and will be calculated before the addition. Also here a link to a question about commutative property in the non-templated case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764604/commutative-oprator-overloading-of-2-different-objects

Comment: @Philipp Thanks for the correction. The **commutative property** is indeed what I 
 need.

Comment: @Rubin yes it is possible to solve the ambiguity without forcing the user to decide the right order to use. Because having a semantic that relies on the order of arguments in a commutative operation goes against POLA.

Comment: The member function is prefered because the **implied object paramenter is not const**!!! Declares spv as const, and you will get the same error message.